# Convert PWM to serial

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, serial, converter

I am currently working with a system that communicates several angular positions and several actuator commands through PWM signals at 500 Hz.

My question is, what is the industry standard for reading PWM signals? Are they converted back to analog? Or is there an IC or module that reads PWM signals and translates them into digital values directly?

Comment: Low-pass filter followed by ADC?

Comment: Please explain what is encoded into your PWM signal and what resolution of encoding is used.

Comment: Use the AK47 of MCUs, an Arduino. Just buy a ready board. Use its internal timer to read the pulse widths with high resolution. Turn those into serial output with the Serial library.

Comment: A PWM stream *is* serial data. Transmit directly. If you need the analog value at the receiver, do a lowpass there, e.g. a digital CIC (Sinc) filter.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am trying to steer clear from the analog domain as I require a rather high precision. The information encoded in the signal are angles measured by encoders.

Comment: @Sam That doesn't make any sense. Use an ADC with sufficient resolution, obviously. "Rather high" is not a technical specification.

Comment: @Neil_UK Aren't AK47 known to be reliable and rugged? An Arduino is rather something like [this](https://artistatexit0.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/img_6030_1_1.jpg).

Comment: @Lundin Yes of course, lets say that I wish to avoid analog signals if possible. I said rather high because I do not know the exact resolution of the information.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please edit new information into your question, rather than post it in comments, otherwise readers have to piece together the full question from fragments. Meanwhile, your question sketches an outline of what you want to to do but with little technical detail. The actual question is just asking for a part recommendation and they're off-topic for the site, meaning the question may be closed. Please edit the question and all all info to clearly detail what you have, what you are trying to do and why, with technical characteristics. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: A PWM period is already analog as far as the duty cycle goes. So I guess you want to avoid PWM then. Good luck with that.

Comment: Can you give more details about how the signal is encoded exactly? One hardware option to decode pulses is the [ESP32 RMT](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v5.0.1/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/rmt.html). Just give it a pin and a few parameters and will give you pulse lengths. This is also implemented in [MicroPython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/esp32.html#rmt) and apparently also in Arduino.

Comment: What kind of encoder it is, does it have a data sheet? The PWM output could be digitally generated so it will have a defined digital resolution. In case the encoder is just a NE555 with a potentiometer, the output pulse length has way more resolution as it encodes an analog value. The question is, what kind of resolution you need?

Comment: @Lundin I was thinking more along the lines of cheap, ubiquitous, able to be used by relatively untrained noobs, and does the job, as long as the job is not too demanding.

Comment: @Neil_UK Except Arduino isn't suitable for any purpose, including learning embedded systems programming.

Comment: @Justme I do not know what kind of sensors I am dealing with, it is basically a black box that sends PWM signals that encode angular positions. I also do not know the resolution of the sensors so I am trying to have the best resolution possible when reading the signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says:

- You having a digital signal (PWM waveform) carrying a measurement
- You want to convert that digital signal into a binary (digital) value.

First, converting the digital waveform to an analogue voltage then back into digital domain would simply lose quality by introducing some amount of non-linearity, noise and inaccuracy. Keep the signal in the digital domain.

Next, the only two measurements that can be taken from a digital PWM waveform are its period and its duty cycle. This will be done by a digital logic circuit. There are several ways this could be implemented but the most commonplace would be:

1. MCU with timer capture/compare module
2. CPLD/FPGA with digital logic circuit designed in an HDL
3. Off-the-shelf IC

To start with, you need to define the PWM waveform characteristics:

- What is the minimum and maximum duty cycle? (min can't be 0%, max can't be 100%, would be a level and not PWM)
- Is its duty cycle a truly analogue variance? (so no discrete steps)
- Or is is digitally generated and there are 'n' steps in the period, each of 't' us time long?
- If analogue, what does the PWM duty cycle range represent as a measurement?
- If digital, what does each PWM duty cycle step represent as a measurement?
- What is the accuracy of the PWM waveform? (i.e. the tolerance on the 500 Hz)

From that, the acceptable and practically possible specifications for the measurement circuit can be identified:

- Sampling period or measurement precision, in measurement steps of 'm' ns/us
- Maximum measurement steps in a PWM cycle, then max steps in duty cycle range

Finally, from the specifications you can select a method.

Most of the time with typical applications in the market, the MCU has enough precision and gets used. It'd be hard to imagine it won't give enough precision with your 500 Hz waveform. Whether it'll give the accuracy, from its crystal frequency tolerance and stability, is probably more of a factor in deciding.

A CPLD/FPGA can be chosen if the PWM needs greater precision, you have other functions a CPLD/FPGA could do or you just prefer to work with them.